# overcoming the 256 character file path barrier in powershell

Tags: windows, powershell

I am trying to find out the size of a folder on a remote server using powershell and I hit the 256 character file path barrier. I tried //?/ but for some reason I can't get it to work. I am using powershell 5.1 on a win8.1 machine

```
get-childitem -path \\fileserver\files\ -recurse | measure-object -property legth -sum
```

Comment: You should look at this article from a PowerShell MVP: https://www.powershellmagazine.com/2012/07/24/jaap-brassers-favorite-powershell-tips-and-tricks/

Comment: The limit is 260 characters, not 256. And the prefix for fullly-qualified paths is \\?\, not `//?/`. [There are various workaround that you can read here](https://superuser.com/a/811155/241386)

Comment: Thank you! I will check out both of them, I am quite new to powershell so I am bound to make a lot of mistakes.